# How to access response in body of POSTMAN

Tags: php, response, postman, codeigniter-3, box-api

[image]

Hi guys,

i want to download an image from app.box i can get display of the image file in postman response(body). but it is not displaying in browser. how can i access that response image from postman

Comment: what is the content type of the response ?

Comment: Are you sending Headers when you make request via browser?\

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: hi nirvair, im sending same headers in postman when i make request via browser, i just copied the curl code and requested via browser, but i couldn't see the response in browser.

Answer (score 2):

Click `code` on top right in Postman screen, then select `cURL`, `Copy to Clipboard`, paste into a terminal, and press Enter to execure the curl command (`apt-get install curl` if you don't have it...).

This will run the curl command postman is executing correctly, downloading the image...

Curl is available also for the *windows* platform, you can download it here: https://curl.haxx.se/windows/ ... And, run `cmd` to open a terminal in *windows*...

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm just copying the phpCurl from postman and using that curl code from my codeigniter application. while doing this approch i couldn't see any response in browser. (https://dev.deliverease.in/box/download_image). the response only displaying in postman. is there any possibility to capture response image and store in server?